# Change time doesn't change when access a file

Tags: timestamp

We know that if we change access time then change time is also get change.
When I read contents of a file by using cat filename

Access time got change but change time doesn't. Why?

Comment: When you read a file, the change time of the file is obviously not modified. But, sometimes the reverse might not occur. Please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368734/last-access-time-not-updated

Comment: Related on [unix.se]: [What is the difference between modify and change in stat command context?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2802/322920)